# php echo link without a href in file add target blank

Tags: php, hyperlink

```
<?php echo auto_link(site_url('guest/view/quote/' . $quote->quote_url_key)); ?>
```

This is creating for instance the following link:

http://domainname.com/guest/view/quote/d163df9c4d426b3ab5ef6247bc380745

How can I add an `target="_blank"` to this php code. Or is there another way to achieve the same.

EDIT 1: Added all scripts from the php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $('#btn_add_item_from_lookup').click(function() {
        $('#modal-placeholder').load("<?php echo site_url('item_lookups/ajax/modal_item_lookups'); ?>/" + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
    });

    $('#btn_add_item').click(function() {
        $('#new_item').clone().appendTo('#item_table').removeAttr('id').addClass('item').show();
    });

    <?php if (!$items) { ?>
        $('#new_item').clone().appendTo('#item_table').removeAttr('id').addClass('item').show();
    <?php } ?>

    $('#btn_save_quote').click(function() {
        var items = [];
        var item_order = 1;
        $('table tr.item').each(function() {
            var row = {};
            $(this).find('input,select,textarea').each(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
                    row[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).is(':checked');                        
                } else {
                    row[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            row['item_order'] = item_order;
            item_order++;
            items.push(row);
        });
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('quotes/ajax/save'); ?>", {
            quote_id: <?php echo $quote_id; ?>,
            quote_number: $('#quote_number').val(),
            quote_date_created: $('#quote_date_created').val(),
            quote_date_expires: $('#quote_date_expires').val(),
            quote_status_id: $('#quote_status_id').val(),
            items: JSON.stringify(items),
            custom: $('input[name^=custom]').serializeArray()
        },
        function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            if (response.success == '1') {
                window.location = "<?php echo site_url('quotes/view'); ?>/" + <?php echo $quote_id; ?>;
            }
            else {
                $('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                for (var key in response.validation_errors) {
                    $('#' + key).parent().parent().addClass('error');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('#btn_generate_pdf').click(function() {
        window.location = '<?php echo site_url('quotes/generate_pdf/' . $quote_id); ?>';
    });

    var fixHelper = function(e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return $helper;
    };

    $("#item_table tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: is that from a certain framework ? There's no auto_link function in PHP

Comment: Have you created a function `auto_link` or any framework you using ?

Comment: @RoyalBg It is part of FusionInvoice. I have been looking all over their support section but it is not in there. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Rikesh I did not create the function. Where should I look to find that function.

Comment: Try `auto_link('url', array('target' => '_blank'));`

Comment: Start with searching this function in your `FusionInvoice` project folder.

Comment: @BlackSheep I have done the following but it is not working: `<?php echo auto_link(site_url('guest/view/quote/' . $quote->quote_url_key), array('target' => '_blank')); ?>`

Comment: @Rikesh Any idea where I should start looking there are 986 files? Is there a standard place to save functions?

Comment: Do not look into the each file but take help of IDE to search in your project folder.

Comment: @Rikesh It probably sound really stupid but what is IDE? Thanks for helping bye the way.

Comment: Learn using computers, before start programming :) btw. couldn't you google "IDE" ?

Comment: @RoyalBg So you know everything about cars. I assume you drive a car. You know how to build staircases. I assume you have a house with 2 floors. Ow and you know how to build bridges because I am sure you crossed one in your life. Come on. Keep real. Thanks for helping! PS: Thanks for the Google hint. Did not thought about that.

Comment: @RoyalBg You don't necessarily need an IDE for using computers :)

Comment: @HennySmafter when they tell me "use cement so your bricks won't fall while building" I would search what is cement and how it is used with bricks. Your dependency is wrong. I would not start building bridges, if I weren't seen or crossed one. So I would not start programming, if I am not familiar enough with the dependencies behind. IDE, as you might already seen, is an integrated development environment, which is commonly used by everyone who is programming. You did not even know what is IDE, but you started programming? I don't want to discourage you, just saying you have to learn back

Comment: @BlackSheep my post about using computers was "how to search to files" question from the OP, not exactly for the IDE

Comment: And mostly, the problem is not that you are trying to program before you learn some other things, the problem is that you automatically ask a question before search it. You could search how to find text in files, and search what is IDE. But instead, you immediately after you did not understand someones sentence, you asked a question in the comments, which is not related to the question in the post.

Comment: @RoyalBg I see where your problem is with my comment. The problem I have with your comments is that it is also not related with the question asked. But thanks for replying.

Comment: Your question were answered from another contributer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it. Not by using any code but by simple explaining to the users to use ctrl + click. It is probably not the best thing. There should be a way to achieve the same with code. But after the long discussion with Royal Bg I thought it would be wise to stop putting oil on the fire.

I hope that in the future someone else takes up the original question and posts an solution for others to benefit from. In the meantime I will accept this as an answer. I hope others do too.